# Alternative for the hamburger icon in webapps

Tags: usability, web-app, mobile-web

I know the hamburger icon for long now, I used it several times and I personally like it. But as it seems, it isn't state of the art.

I am wondering, what would be a good alternative for web apps? Because as far as I can see, the hamburger icon is the only platform independent icon available.

In native mobile apps, there are far better solutions, in iOS the tab bar and in Windows Phone you have hub apps.

But both concepts you cannot bring easy in the mobile web world without making others feel uncomfortable. So, what should we use, instead of the hamburger icon for a site like http://getbootstrap.com/.

Here are two articles:

- https://lmjabreu.com/post/why-and-how-to-avoid-hamburger-menus/
- http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/24/before-the-hamburger-button-kills-you/

Comment: I don't understand the question. The two sources you cite already discuss all of your points. So, what are you asking here exactly?

Comment: The 'whys' they point out are not exactly clear to me. Also they concentrate on plattform specific apps, not web apps.

Comment: I find the 'whys' there well explained and illustrated. Even when the author uses jargon ("navigation friction"), the context seems sufficient to understand it. Your question would be much more answerable if you can explain what exactly you don't understand in the article. It might turn out that your question title is misleading, and what you need is not an explanation of hamburger icons (which is explained in the article) but of basic UX concepts which the article uses but are not known to you yet.

Comment: @RumiP. I hope it is better now :)

Comment: I still find it confusing. Your title seems to ask if it's "state of the art" (whatever you understand under the term). In the body, you seem to be convinced that it is not state of the art, based on two articles you have read. So, your title and body contradict each other. And then you ask what to use instead - when both articles tell you that the problems they speak of are solved by using a Tab bar.

Comment: @RumiP. Another edit. The articles say clearly for native apps, but not for websites ;)

Comment: `For websites, I believe it’s best to still review the IA but instead of using these iOS patterns, simply display the navigation in the website header as a list - example.` - right from the first article you cited. Also, why would you assume that the problem they describe is shared between apps and websites, but the solution is specific to apps? It doesn't make sense. If you agree with them, place a toolbar look alike on your web page.

Comment: If it's understood, what's the problem? People still use the floppy disk icon for "save," though I don't think anyone would call it a "state of the art" icon. Unless you've seen lots your actual customers having problems understanding where your menu is, move on to the next thing :-)

Comment: Why the need for an alternative icon? What is the problem with using something that is likely widely understood? Without knowing the reason for wanting an alternative icon (or whatever the problem is), it is pretty difficult to suggest an alternative solution for you.

Comment: @zigojacko I personally just would like to know, if there is a better solution. That is also widely understood. And not just another icon.

Answer (score 1):

You still could use something like a tapbar on mobile (see twitter.com for example) or build a navigation-bar which also includes some navigation elements (pinterest). Personally I think that for now the hamburger button isn't the worst option (facebook still has it on it's webapp version) and we shouln't kill it just yet. Yes there are drawbacks, but pretty much every pattern has its drawbacks. So nothing to freak out IMHO.

More important than the navigation system you use, should be how you organize your data. IMHO Information Architecture (IA) will have the most profound impact on the user experience.